# unable to install the engine devise for my rails app. I have 5 error messages pertaining to it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am trying to get some hands-on experience with using Devise and Rails.

This is what I typed:

```
rails generate devise:install
```

This is what I got:

```
create  config/initializers/devise.rb
create  config/locales/devise.en.yml
===============================================================================

Some setup you must do manually if you haven't yet:

  1. Ensure you have defined default url options in your environments files. Here
     is an example of default_url_options appropriate for a development environment
     in config/environments/development.rb:

       config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }

     In production, :host should be set to the actual host of your application.

  2. Ensure you have defined root_url to *something* in your config/routes.rb.
     For example:

       root :to => "home#index"

  3. Ensure you have flash messages in app/views/layouts/application.html.erb.
     For example:

       <p class="notice"><%= notice %></p>
       <p class="alert"><%= alert %></p>

  4. If you are deploying on Heroku with Rails 3.2 only, you may want to set:

       config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false

     On config/application.rb forcing your application to not access the DB
     or load models when precompiling your assets.

  5. You can copy Devise views (for customization) to your app by running:

       rails g devise:views

===============================================================================
```

This is my latest commit. https://github.com/simkimsia/riding-rails-with-angularjs/commit/dc8df19b30237b1a44fb8cf8bc2b9d343c4ce47f

As you can see, I have already resolved the first 3 issues.

I am not using `Heroku` and I am certain I do not need to copy Devise views.

My ruby version.

```
www-data@ubuntu:~$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-linux]
```

My rails version:

```
www-data@ubuntu:~$ rails -v
Rails 4.0.1
```

I am on Mac OS X Lion and running a Ubuntu 12.10 on a virtual box.

Do let me know what other information I need to provide to better troubleshoot this issue.

Comment: it´s not an error, it´s just an information. What´s wrong ?

Comment: These are only setup points.......not an error

Comment: What should I do to overcome the issue then? Or what additional information should I provide?

Comment: Your devise is now setup. You have to rails generate devise MODEL to start using devise. Looks here : https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

Comment: @Ludovic Oh, I get it. Looks like a misunderstanding on my part. Should I close this question or I write an answer about misunderstanding the messages?

Comment: @KimSia Maybe you should write an answer and +1 my first and second comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I misunderstood the situation.

The long text does not indicate anything is wrong. It suggests possible follow up actions.

This is not an error per se.

See Ludovic comments in my question for clarification.